# Scala-redis Client connection to RedisCloud on Heroku issues

Tags: scala, heroku, redis

I am using the new non-blocking redis client  https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis to connect to Rediscloud DB on Heroku.
The connection string needed is for e.g of following format.

redis://rediscloud:@pub-redis-.us-east-1-3.4.ec2.garantiadata.com:

Note that it includes a password string in the connection string.

My question is how do I use the RedisClient object to supply the password which has the signature like this according to the code doc?

object RedisClient {

```
def apply(host: String, port: Int = 6379, name: String = defaultName,
        settings: RedisClientSettings = RedisClientSettings())(
```

implicit refFactory:ActorRefFactory): RedisClient  ....

......

......

}

Comment: It is actually redis://rediscloud:<<password-string here>>@pub-redis-<<port-number-here>>.us-east-1-3.4.ec2.garantiadata.com:<<port-number-here>>. The charadters < and > were gobbled by the html renderer I suppose!

Comment: did you find a solution? facing this too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Redis documentation, there is actually no concept of a username. The [AUTH command](http://redis.io/commands/AUTH) only takes a password.

Scala-redis uses the provided `secret` argument to [do the authentication](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/00c5b04d352183ff0b028c16116db7ac2f363cb5/src/main/scala/com/redis/Operations.scala#L156) using `AUTH`.

In the [Heroku example for Redis Cloud](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#using-redis-from-java), they provide an example of how to connect using JedisPool (a Java Redis library). They could do a better job of mentioning it, but nowhere in the documentation do they actually use the username from the Redis URL.

In the Java example, they simply split the user information component `user:password` and extract just the second part after the colon: `password`. The username is never used.

Going back to your question about Scala-redis, the constructor you want is:

```
RedisClient(override val host: String, override val port: Int,
    override val database: Int = 0, override val secret: Option[Any] = None, override val timeout : Int = 0)
```

Where `secret` is the password component of your Redis URL.

I ended up using the following in my own application:

```
val redisClient = Properties.envOrNone("REDISCLOUD_URL") match {
      case Some(redisUrl) => {
        val redisUri = new URI(redisUrl)
        val host = redisUri.getHost()
        val port = redisUri.getPort()
        val secret = Try(redisUri.getUserInfo().split(":",2).last).toOption
        new RedisClient(host, port, secret = secret)
      }
      case _ => {
          // Deal with missing configuration here
      }
    }
```